# thousands of values to be searched

Tags: sql, search

simple search query
select * from table where id = id_1;
id_1,......................................id_2000

is there a way to search all these ids with one query or pl/sql code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (id_1, id_2, ... id_2000);
```

or if the IDs are strings:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('id_'1, 'id_2', ... 'id_2000');
```

Comment: ids could be any string 'abc',' xyz',...........;'yrt'

Comment: I've updated the answer to show you what using strings would look like.

Comment: I have list of  1000+ ids in the excel sheet, is it possible to read from the excel sheet, execute the query and write the result to a excel sheet/sqldeveloper output